# An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: java, maven

I get my Apache Storm from http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/storm/apache-storm-0.9.3/apache-storm-0.9.3.tar.gz

I never modified any thing in the /home/user/storm/examples/storm-starter/ directory.

When I run this command

`mvn exec:java -D storm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology`

in the /home/user/storm/examples/storm-starter/, it gives the error as below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
MojoExecutionException - Apache Maven - Apache Software Foundation
cwiki.apache.org
```

Anyone know what is the problem & how to solve it?
I wish can provide me a detail solution as I am a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: Did you run mvn clean install before executing the topology?

Comment: As recommended run `mvn -X` to get detailed description of your problem

Comment: after I had run mvn clean install &  mvn -X exec:java -D storm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology 


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Go to the path where your pom.xml file exists and run this command

```
mvn -e -f pom.xml compile exec:java -D storm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

Try adding this to your pom.xml and run the above command.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
      <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
      <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
      <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: After I try this command: mvn -e -f pom.xml compile exec:java -D storm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology    
    
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-starter: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.InterruptedException

Comment: DivakarDass, my original pom.xml already include that part, just at <includePluginDependencies> is false instead of true, I modified it to true according to your version. then I re-run:

mvn clean install
mvn package
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -D storm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology

however, the same error still persist.